# How to Compare Date time in moment js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

Hi I need to validate two date time moment instances,
Using this [Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime) to get time we can select hour min sec in this.
I need validate if selected Date time is after or before like you see in code .I'm having confusion will it validate date with time ?
How to compare selected date time hour min sec  in isAfter/isBefore

```
 function DateValidate(selectedDate,type){ //selected date in moment instance
      let isValid=false
      const {startTime,endTime}=dateTime // from state 
       if(type==='start'&& endTime){
            isValid=selectedDate.isAfter(endTime);
          }else if(type==='end'&& startTime){
          isValid=selectedDate.isBefore(startTime);
          }
       return isValid
      }
```

should i need to format selected date needed format -(dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss) and then apply isBefore/isafter ?
Please help...

Comment: Can you share some sample input and output?

Comment: Hi @HassanImam

I need know that this implementation will validate time or I  need to format current date in dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss then validate

Comment: Why do you have two `selectedDate` in function? One in argument and other on line 3.

Comment: Sorry it my mistake I have updated the question

Comment: @Dev, if you have a valid moment object then it will validate time as well(you don't need to format the date).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will validate date along with the time. Here is the code which shows the 1 second difference between two dates.

```
const out = document.getElementById('output');

const today = moment();
var afterToday;
setTimeout(()=>{
    afterToday = moment();
}, 1000)

setTimeout(()=>{

    //const diff = afterToday.isAfter(today);
  const diff = today.isAfter(afterToday);
  out.innerText = diff;
}, 2000)
```

To see it in action take a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6q32tL4v/).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, in your example, the selectedDate is not a valid moment object. selectedDate needs to be a valid moment object in order to successfully apply the isAfter() and isBefore() methods, and startTime and endTime must also be in the correct format. See the examples in the docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/.

If you know the format ahead of time, you can pass that as the second argument into moment(). See the relevant part of the docs: momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format. In your example, something like `moment("10/09/1997 02:31:01", "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")`

Comment: Yes @Omid all date used is moment object .How do format the selected date the apply isAfter /isBefore .should i need to format  dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss like this 

how do i do that

Comment: If you know the format ahead of time, you can pass that as the second argument into moment(). See the relevant part of the docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/. In your example, something like `moment("10/09/1997 02:31:01", "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")`